# Program to remove thin strip from inner part of image

Tags: photo-editing

At present I have a 2x2 grid of 4 photo images.  These 4 images are separated by 30 pixel wide white strips, in the middle, one horizontal, one vertical.

I would like to reduce the white separation strips to just 10 pixels wide.

Can anyone think of software that can remove an inner strip, top to bottom, or side to side, and then simply stitch what's left together again.  In the present case the removed strip would be 20 pixels wide.

Thanks,
Nicholas Kormanik

Comment: You want to do this once, or repeatedly?  Fully automated, or manual steps?

Comment: Just one single photo to deal with, thank goodness.  Manually would be fine -- highlight, say, the strip to be deleted one way, do it, highlight the strip to be deleted the other way, do it.  Done.

Comment: Then Chris Conways answer would do it. Select the left half up to, or including some of the white.  Select move tool, and arrow key to move 20 pixels to the right.  Repeat vertically. Crop.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done manually, and easily with any version of Photoshop.

Simply use the marquee tool (M) to select an image row or column, then the move tool (V) to adjust the position of that row or column to reduce the width/height of the white area.

After that process you can either use the trim function (edit > trim) to remove any excess canvas, or again use the marquee tool to select the area you would like to keep, then crop (edit > crop) to remove the unwanted edges.

If this is something you need to do more than once, a batch process action could be set up easily using the above steps

Comment: Additionally, if the OP doesn't have a sizeable chunk of money to drop on Photoshop (even Elements isn't exactly _cheap_), he can do exactly the same thing with GIMP, which is of course free.

Comment: This particular task is actually performable even in Windows' Paint. It has selection and move tools.

Comment: @Jahaziel - True but you lose control of the output quality if you use paint.